# Can't figure out a solution for 27V, 3A supply

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, zener

I have a pretty weird situation. I need to produce 27V, 3A from a supply of 27.5V. At first I thought of using a zener as the voltage regulator but I could not find a zener of over 81mW: with zener as voltage regulator the shunt resistor has to be of almost 0 ohms (0.166 ohms to be precise), since I need a drop of 0.5V at the resistor. I thought of using a voltage divider but the resistors will wear out with time which is not required.

What should I do? If I use a chip (i.e. a DC DC converter) the input voltage should be at least Vout+4V, which is not the scenario here. Can anyone suggest me any regulator I might have skipped in my research?

Also I read somewhere that using zener as voltage regulator is not the best approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: How stable is the input supply? It is incredibly close to the output you need already.

Comment: Provide info about your voltage source

Comment: The voltage source is stable with 90% efficiency, and is capable of providing 27V @ 4A

Comment: So you just need to get 3A instead of 4A?

Comment: Is there a particular reason the load requires such accurate regulation? 0.5V at 27V is less than 2% error. Most quality IC regulators can't provide that much accuracy.

Comment: You quote the maximum current draw (3A) but what might your minimum current draw be whilst still producing 27V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this just by putting a diode in series with the load.

The [MBRS320](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MB/MBRS320.pdf) is rated for 4A at 105°C, and has a V\$_{f}\$ of 0.5v at 3A.  So it will drop the 27.5v down to exactly 27v.

It is [available from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MBRS320/MBRS320CT-ND/3042646) for 53 cents.

Another possibility is the [VS-50WQ04FNPbF](http://www.vishay.com/docs/94233/50wq04fn.pdf) which has a slightly less V\$_{f}\$ of 0.45v at 3A (so it will drop the 27.5v down to 27.05v), the advantage is it is rated for 5.5A so it may run a little cooler.

It is [available from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VS-50WQ04FNPBF/VS-50WQ04FNPBF-ND/3424550) for $1.47.

If you are making a buy from Digi-Key you might want to buy both and see how they work out.